# how do I use JavaScript to flip a SVG node horizontally?

Tags: svg

Say I have a SVG in my HTML like:

`<svg id="graph">....</svg>`

Is it possible to use some simple JavaScript to flip it horizontally?

like this:

`$('#graph').flip();`

Comment: All the text would be upside down. If that's OK you want something along the lines of transform="scale(1, -1)" applied to a `<g>` child of the svg element.

Comment: what if I want to keep the text remain the correct direction? is there a way?

Comment: You'd have to flip all the text back again.